# How many numbers between 1 and d are dividing d - not restricted to a particular language

Tags: python

I am actually solving the Problem 243 on Project Euler.

### If you know the Problem 243:

The numbers d I am going to check the resilience for, are going to be multiplies of prime numbers, so they won't be dividable with 2 and all other primes up to d. The quickest function I can think of works like this:

```
def checkUnDivisibility(d, primeList):
    for prime in primeList:
        if d%prime == 0: return False
    return True

def resilience(d, primeList):
    allFractions = d-1
    undivisibleFractions = 2 # 2 that are not divisible with d are 1 and d-1
    for numerator in range(3, d-2, 2): 
        if checkUnDivisibility(numerator, primeList): undivisibleFractions +=  1
        elif gcd(d, numerator) == 1: undivisibleFractions += 1
    print("the number of undivisible fractions is " + undivisibleFractions)
```

### If you do not know the Problem 243:

if you write down all fractions with the numerator going from 1 to d and the denominator d, I want to know how many fractions there is, that can't be cancelled down.

For example, for d = 6:

Fractions: 1/6, 2/6, 3/6, 4/6, 5/6, 6/6. Those that can't be cancelled down are 1/6 and 5/6.

I know that when the denominator is a prime number, the number of those fractions is the same as the number of all the denominators and I know that 1/d and (d-1)/d are not going to be cancellable, and I do know how to write a function that will calculate the number of those fractions.

But the thing is, I am calculating this for some huge numbers and I want to have a quicker function. Is there any kind of trick or an algorithm for calculating the number of those with a function or a formula or something?

I would really appreciate the answer because I have been solving the problem for a few days now and still can't solve it for a really big d (around 15-30 digits).

Comment: This is known as the [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). It can be done faster than what you have, but it's still really hard to calculate. However, Project Euler problem 243 *does not require you to calculate totients of arbitrary numbers*. It's a lot easier to construct a number x to match a totient(x)/x bound than it is to calculate totient(x)/x values until you find a match, since you know the prime factorization of your constructed x.

Comment: Didn't know I don't need it, I will try looking it up, thank you!